# How to debug an XFCE launcher which fails to launch its app?

Tags: xfce, application, launcher

I have a command for one of my launchers:

```
discord
```

That's all. When launch from the terminal, it runs fine, [Discord](https://discordapp.com/) starts as intended.

When I click the launcher, nothing happens. I see a small burst of CPU activity on the CPU monitor, that's all. Nothing starts.

Specifying the absolute path does not solve the problem.

What about using the full path to "Discord" instead of "discord"? This is what gets added when I simply add an "existing item" to the launcher:

```
/usr/share/discord/Discord
```

Nope. Nothing.

However, if I run `/usr/share/discord/Discord` in the terminal, it starts fine again.

Now, maybe there is a third way, the "actual" way of starting Discord? I don't really care, I want to know why it works in the terminal, and why it doesn't work in the launcher -- with the exact same command!

How do I debug this? How can I see the output of the obviously failed command (as indicated by the little burst in CPU activity)?

Comment: Know nothing about discord but you can try with a laucher like : xterm -e sh -c 'discord'

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had renamed my homedir's name. After going into various hidden subdirectories and doing a recursive search and replace to change any occurrence of the old username to the new one, XFCE started working again.

Note that this was a problem even for **new** launchers, not just existing ones.

Comment: Would be nice to know how you came to this conclusion. Im having similar issues but i dont think ive changed my homedir.